# Long response time with static express files

Tags: node.js, express

I've a simple Express.js app with some static files served by Express.js itself.

When I open the index.html page it tries to load the `bundle.js` script but it takes ages, it does not happen everytime but only sometimes without any evident reason...

It happens with any kind of file, sometimes js, sometimes css.

My app is something like this:

```
var app = require("express")();
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use("/bower_components", express.static(__dirname + "/bower_components"));
app.listen(3000);
```

I'm running the app locally.. why is there this problem?

[image]

Comment: Not sure, since we don't know what your code is.  Add some debugging to your application to verify when the request is received and processed.

Comment: Not sure how to debug the "express.static" middleware... it doesn't expose much to debug...

Comment: Add your own debugging statements to the middleware's source code itself. Or try making individual routes for each file that just do `fs.createReadStream('main.css').pipe(res);` to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @FezVrasta Fire up a packet sniffer and confirm what you're seeing in your browser.  I suspect that the connection is remaining open for some reason.  In any case, I cannot reproduce your issue.  What version of Express are you using?

Comment: I'm with 4.8.6... the problem is real because the page hangs waiting for the JS or for the CSS and starts working only after the file is loaded.